# Logo on mobile view not centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for the noob question.I've bought a template in order to practice and I have the next situation.
I'm trying to obtain a centered logo for mobile device and I simply can not figure what is the problem.

I've uploaded the code on a domain: http://digitalicus.com/ to simplify the process of explaining.

Any advice's are much appreciated.

Vlad

Comment: Can you please include example code in your question, and explain what you have tried already?

Comment: This is a CSS issue and is a simple fix.  Seeing code is always preferable to click bait.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

with this css your can align your logo to center:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  .header-content-one .d-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .header-content-one .d-flex a{
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

I've setted up a breakpoint to 767px (the code work only for smaller screen) change it to the measure you want.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using "display: flex" which could be part of the problem. You could try using display: "inline-block" or "display: flex-box" which will start you in the right direction. Check out this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/